# Ansible register all variables from list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a problem with iterating and registering output to the variable. I need to get all xml files paths in a directory.

Script:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     - name: Find xml files
       win_find:
          paths: C:\Directory
          patterns: ['*.xml']
       register: filesfind
     - name: set facts
       set_fact:
          find: "{{ filesfind.files.0.path }}"
```

which outputs:

```
ok: [host] => {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 17,
    "files": [
        {
            "attributes": "Archive",
            "checksum": "dd1f259408cf08a40da492238101344824199594",
            "creationtime": 1586955271.1427224,
            "extension": ".xml",
            "filename": "File1.xml",
            "isarchive": true,
            "isdir": false,
            "ishidden": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreadonly": false,
            "isshared": false,
            "lastaccesstime": 1586955271.1427224,
            "lastwritetime": 1586867409.3292916,
            "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
            "path": "C:\\Directory\\File1.xml",
            "size": 218428
        },
        {
            "attributes": "Archive",
            "checksum": "dd1f259408cf08a40da492238101344824199594",
            "creationtime": 1586867369.8255088,
            "extension": ".xml",
            "filename": "File2.xml",
            "isarchive": true,
            "isdir": false,
            "ishidden": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreadonly": false,
            "isshared": false,
            "lastaccesstime": 1586867369.8255088,
            "lastwritetime": 1586867409.3292916,
            "owner": "BUILTIN\\Administrators",
            "path": "C:\\Directory\\File2.xml",
            "size": 218428
        }
    ],
    "matched": 2
```

It only registers the files[0].path that I defined in the playbook. How can I iterate over all list indexes or items and get all paths into one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter "map" does the job. The task below

```
    - set_fact:
        myfind: "{{ filesfind.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: myfind
```

gives

```
    "myfind": [
        "C:\\Directory\\File1.xml", 
        "C:\\Directory\\File2.xml"
    ]
```